# FBML + jquery Validation + Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, fbml

In my local machine i have a scaffold that uses Jquery Validation plugin for the field's validation.

Now i want to add that to a fbml facebook application, but i'm haven't been able to load the jquery javascript and the jquery Validation plugin into the app, does anybody now how to do that? or maybe someone could suggest me a better way of doing validation inside a facebook application.

Thanks in Advance

Ernesto Carrión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery won't work in an FBML application. Facebook sanitizes any javascript and converts it to FBJS. Some things just aren't allowed. 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS

What you would need to do is make your application an iframe application, which is what Facebook is recommending for all new applications. You would then use Facebook Connect/OpenGraph to render FBML. You can then load and use any external libs that you want.

Comment: You gave me the only answer i didn't want to hear, ;)